# Regex: Capture Group Matching a Character That Should be Excluded

Tags: .net, regex

I'm having trouble with a regex solution where I believe my solution is correct, but the matching is not as I would expect.

Can someone please help me understand where my thinking is going wrong?

Here is the problem I am solving, my regex, and what is going wrong:

**Problem To Solve**

I am given a series of strings representing folders, for example:

```
"TopLevelFolder"
"TopLevelFolder\Parent"
"TopLevelFolder\Parent\Child"
```

I am aiming to convert these into the following strings for displaying in a select list:

```
"TopLevelFolder"
"...\Parent"
"...\...\Child"
```

**My Regex**

Engine: Dot Net

Language: C#

```
(([^\\]+\\)+)
```

regex101 example:

https://regex101.com/r/zY1oM5/1

This regex is trying to: One or more times, find one or more characters that aren't a backslash, and then a backslash, and put that match in a capture group.

For example, in "TopLevel\Parent\Child", put each of "TopLevel\" and "Parent\" in a capture group.

**What's Going Wrong**

The returned capture groups for this regex in this example include:

```
"TopLevel\Parent\"
"Parent\"
```

I believe the first group should not be being captured, because I asked that the characters before the final backslash not include a backslash.

Clearly, my expectations and understanding are wrong. What should I be doing here, and how is my understanding wrong?

Comment: You may also specify the programming language to be used, just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want a [lazy match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions). Remove the outer capturing group and then add the `?` quantifier at the end of the expression so that `+` is no longer [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions). This will allow each substring to be captured as expected.

```
/([^\\]+\\)+?/g
```

An input of `TopLevel\Parent\Child` will return:

```
TopLevel\
Parent\
```

[**Updated Example**](https://regex101.com/r/kE4dG4/1)

---

Then you can replace `/([^\\]+\\)+?/g` with `..\\`.

An input of `TopLevelFolder\Parent\Child` would output: `..\..\Child`.

And likewise, `TopLevelFolder\Parent` would output `..\Parent`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much! It turns out I was also missing the necessary global modifier that you added. Much appreciated :)